# Regex - Not pick up second set of tags

Tags: regex

Given the following line, how do I get the regex below from picking up the second set of SPAN tags. I want the zip, not the extend zip.

```
<TD width="20%">Zip Code: <B><SPAN class="TableBody clsBold">06902</SPAN>-<SPAN class="TableBody clsBold"> 2630</SPAN></B></TD></TR>
```

Regex:

```
<TD.+>([(\s)A-Za-z#]+:)\s*<B><SPAN class="TableBody.*">([\d\s#a-zA-Z$,]+)</SPAN>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<TD.+>([(\s)A-Za-z#]+:)\s*<B><SPAN class="TableBody.*?">([\d\s#a-zA-Z$,]+)</SPAN>`

[Your regex was close](http://regexr.com?31565), but the `TableBody.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and adding a `?` after `.*` makes it lazy so it doesn't grab the entire next portion of tags.